# Method orders in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewdidload

I have methods in viewDidLoad, and it seems like the order of methods getting called is weird.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Get Location
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    // Retrieve Data
    [self retrieveData];
}
```

After viewDidLoad is called, it calls the retrieveData method before locationManager.

Shouldn't the locationManager be called before retrieveData because of the order?

I am new in Objective C, thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your need call your method in inside the delegate methods, so remove the `[self retrieveData];` from `ViewDidLoad` and add into inside the `didFailWithError` or `didUpdateLocations` methods.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Get Location
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                 message:@"Failed to Get Your Location"              
                                delegate:nil 
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];

 // call here 
  [self retrieveData];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

  // set or stop your location update
  manager = nil;
  [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
  [manager stopUpdatingLocation];


    CLLocation *newLocation = locations[[locations count] -1];
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

if (currentLocation != nil) {
   NSLog(@"latitude: %@", latitude);
   NSLog(@"longitude: @"%@", longitude);
}else {
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" 
                                                     delegate:nil 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

// call here
[self retrieveData];

}
```

**Note**

> objective -C is the interpreter , it execute the every in step by step , so or may be your [self retrieveData]; is called in main thread, that is the reason it execute in prior.

Comment: else use another choice use NSTimer for delay to call [self retrieveData]; may be it will execute in some delay and fulfill your needs also.

Comment: Well that works, but the [self retrieveData] is getting called every single second with the location update... I just need to call it once when the app starts.

Comment: simple , you forget  to stop your update location on delegate methods.  this is the reason it called on every seconds, check the updated answer bro

Comment: I already have stopUpdatingLocation in locationManager, but I tried your code. It still keeps updating the location...

Comment: without [self retrieveData] in locationManager it stops

Comment: what , can you show your code on inside retrieveData methods

Comment: sir, my brain must have stopped working for a sec. I had startUpdatingLocation in retrieveData. After taking that out it worked just fine. Thank you so much for your help.